# How to map over this specific json object

Tags: reactjs

I have a json object that i can't find a way to map over it.
I get it via my api in the backend.

My Json:

```
{
  "cn": [
    "Hermes Conrad"
  ], 
  "description": [
    "Human"
  ], 
  "mail": [
    "hermes@planetexpress.com"
  ], 
  "ou": [
    "Office Management"
  ], 
  "sn": [
    "Conrad"
  ], 
  "uid": [
    "hermes"
  ]
}
```

My component:

```
export default function UserDetails({ data }) {

  const classes = useStyles()


  return (

     <div className={classes.root} >
       <h1>User Details</h1>
       <Table className={classes.table} size="small">
         <TableHead>
           <TableRow>
             <TableCell align="left">cn</TableCell>
             <TableCell align="left">description</TableCell>
             <TableCell align="left">mail</TableCell>
             <TableCell align="left">ou</TableCell>
             <TableCell align="left">sn</TableCell>
             <TableCell align="left">uid</TableCell>
           </TableRow>
         </TableHead>
         <TableBody>
           {data.map(details => (
             <TableRow key={details.cn}>
               <TableCell component="th" scope="row"> </TableCell>
               <TableCell align="left">{details.cn}</TableCell>
               <TableCell align="left">{details.description}</TableCell>
               <TableCell align="left">{details.mail}</TableCell>
               <TableCell align="left">{details.ou}</TableCell>
               <TableCell align="left">{details.sn}</TableCell>
               <TableCell align="left">{details.uid}</TableCell>
             </TableRow>
           ))}
         </TableBody>
       </Table>
     </div>
   )
}
```

the data holds my json object, if i console log it i can see it, but if i just try out this code it does nothing.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to `map` over `data` if its an object.

Comment: how will your json represent multiple data?

Comment: I fetch the data with my route in the backend, i pass the parameter cn and i get a specific user details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with just solving this problem, you can use `Object.keys()` to grad the keys as -

```js
const keys = Object.keys(INPUT);
// You get an array of keys as return value
```

Loop over the keys and parse the response as key value pairs:

```js
const getMappedData = () => {
    const keys = Object.keys(INPUT);
    const parsedOutput = {};
    keys.forEach(key => {
      const value = INPUT[key][0]; // considering the json you have
      parsedOutput[key] = value;
    })

    return parsedOutput;
  }
```

Then you'd have a `details` object of which you can read values like -

```js
<TableCell align="left">{details.description}</TableCell>
<TableCell align="left">{details.mail}</TableCell>
```

**Better solution**

> Consider the email property, if only one email is assigned to a customer, the API response should contain a key-value pair, where value is a type of string and is NOT an array.

So if you change the API implementation to respond with something like this -

```
{
    "cn":"Hermes Conrad", 
    "description": "Human",
    "mail":"hermes@planetexpress.com",
    "ou": "Office Management",
    "sn": "Conrad",
    "uid": "hermes"
}
```

So instead of grabbing the keys of INPUT, you could directly use the object as:

```js
...
<TableCell align="left">{details.description}</TableCell>
<TableCell align="left">{details.mail}</TableCell>
...
```

> You won't even have to use a mapper we used earlier.

**IMP NOTE**

Since you're doing -

```js
 {data.map(details => ( ...
```

You're assuming this -

1. **Your `data` is an array. e.g. data contains -**

```
[
{
  "cn": [
    "Hermes Conrad"
  ], 
  "description": [
    "Human"
  ], 
  "mail": [
    "hermes@planetexpress.com"
  ], 
  "ou": [
    "Office Management"
  ], 
  "sn": [
    "Conrad"
  ], 
  "uid": [
    "hermes"
  ]
},
{
  "cn": [
    "Hermes Conrad Jr."
  ], 
  "description": [
    "Human"
  ], 
  "mail": [
    "hermes2@planetexpress.com"
  ], 
  "ou": [
    "Office Management"
  ], 
  "sn": [
    "Conrad2"
  ], 
  "uid": [
    "hermes2"
  ]
}
]
```

2. **You `data` always has some value.**
   You should guard it by checking the length of data.

```js
...
const hasData = data && data.length !== 0;
return (
    { hasData && data.map(details => ( ...
...
```

> Sandbox for this is available [here](https://codepen.io/pritam-patil/pen/MWWjPgG?editors=0010).

Comment: You sir are a machine, i was using other code provided bellow, but i need to get each item, so the other ways would't work. So i use your example and worked like a charm.

Comment: Thanks. Happy that I could help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert JSON object into Array typed data to use map.

```
Object.entries(jsonObj).map();
```

```js
const jsonObj = {
  "cn": [
    "Hermes Conrad"
  ], 
  "description": [
    "Human"
  ], 
  "mail": [
    "hermes@planetexpress.com"
  ], 
  "ou": [
    "Office Management"
  ], 
  "sn": [
    "Conrad"
  ], 
  "uid": [
    "hermes"
  ]
};
Object.entries(jsonObj).map(([key, value], index) =>  console.log(`${index}. ${key}: ${value[0]}`));
```

So your component could be implemented like below;

```
   <TableRow>
      <TableCell component="th" scope="row"> </TableCell>
      {
         Object.entries(details).map(([key, value]) => (<TableCell align="left">{value[0]}</TableCell>)) 
      }
   </TableRow>
```

Comment: Antonio this is working on console log, how to i adapt to my table, thanks a lot

Comment: Antonio, can i get the cn to pass as key?

Comment: i mean like, if i just want to print the "cn " insted of all information, if i pass value[0] it gets all information.

Comment: if i do this `{Object.entries(data)[0]}` i get `cnHermes Conrad` but i just want to get Hermes Conrad, thanks once again

Comment: Try this. `Object.values(data)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the first element from each array, so place [0] inside each element.

```js
const classes = useStyles()


  return (

     <div className={classes.root} >
       <h1>User Details</h1>
       <Table className={classes.table} size="small">
         <TableHead>
           <TableRow>
             <TableCell align="left">cn</TableCell>
             <TableCell align="left">description</TableCell>
             <TableCell align="left">mail</TableCell>
             <TableCell align="left">ou</TableCell>
             <TableCell align="left">sn</TableCell>
             <TableCell align="left">uid</TableCell>
           </TableRow>
         </TableHead>
         <TableBody>
           {data.map(details => (
             <TableRow key={details.cn[0]}>
               <TableCell component="th" scope="row"> </TableCell>
               <TableCell align="left">{details.cn[0]}</TableCell>
               <TableCell align="left">{details.description[0]}</TableCell>
               <TableCell align="left">{details.mail[0]}</TableCell>
               <TableCell align="left">{details.ou[0]}</TableCell>
               <TableCell align="left">{details.sn[0]}</TableCell>
               <TableCell align="left">{details.uid[0]}</TableCell>
             </TableRow>
           ))}
         </TableBody>
       </Table>
     </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: MilosMarkoni it didn't work, my console log displays this: `{cn: Array(1), description: Array(1), mail: Array(1), ou: Array(1), sn: Array(1), …}
cn: ["Hermes Conrad"]
description: ["Human"]
mail: ["hermes@planetexpress.com"]
ou: ["Office Management"]
sn: ["Conrad"]
uid: ["hermes"]`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot map on objects, it has to be array, otherwise you'll get:

> Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function

To map on object data you could use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), here is your return:

```
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>User Details</h1>
      <Table size="small">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell align="left">cn</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">description</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">mail</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">ou</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">sn</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">uid</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          <TableRow>
            {Object.keys(data).map(key => (
              <TableCell align="left" key={key}>
                {data[key][0]}
              </TableCell>
            ))}
          </TableRow>
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
```

And here is a working [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-archimedes-11xgd)

Comment: Ok I've created a sandbox for your reference and mine as well, Answer is UPDATED let me know if you have any questions

Comment: This solution worked as well thanks, but i also need the cn to be passed as key cause i will need it to create a dynamic route for each user.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your JSON structure is weird,
it is supposed to contain an array of objects.
it should be something like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "cn": "Hermes Conrad",
      "description": "Human",
      "mail": "hermes@planetexpress.com",
      "ou": "Office Management",
      "sn": "Conrad",
      "uid": "hermes"
    },
    {
        "cn": "someone else",
        "description": "Human",
        "mail": "abc@xyz.com",
        "ou": "pqr",
        "sn": "xyz",
        "uid": "def"
      }
  ]
}
```

Convert the JSON to a JavaScript Object

```
const jsObj = JSON.parse(jsonObj);
```

Now that the JSON is converted to JS object, data will be an array of objects

Now, you can map it like you would normally do:

```
{jsObj.data.map(x => (
    <TableRow key={x.cn}>
        <TableCell component="th" scope="row"> </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">{x.cn}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">{x.description}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">{x.mail}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">{x.ou}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">{x.sn}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="left">{x.uid}</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
))}
```

Comment: I get a json per user, i have a route that fetches the details for each user, you pass the cn on the route

Answer (score 0):

to map this specific JSON :

```
{
  "cn": [
    "Hermes Conrad"
  ], 
  "description": [
    "Human"
  ], 
  "mail": [
    "hermes@planetexpress.com"
  ], 
  "ou": [
    "Office Management"
  ], 
  "sn": [
    "Conrad"
  ], 
  "uid": [
    "hermes"
  ]
}
```

First parse JSON

```
const data = JSON.parse(jsonObj);
```

And then map it like this :

```
<TableRow key={data['cn'][0]}>
<TableCell component="th" scope="row"> </TableCell>
{Object.keys(data).map(k => (
    <TableCell align="left">{data[k][0]}</TableCell>  
))}
</TableRow
```

>